# Get Jacoco coverage report in xml format

Tags: xml, code-coverage, jacoco

I want to get the jacoco code coverage report in an xml format.
Ex:

My app:

```
package pac1 
Class Class1{
public void method1(){}
}
```

My test:

```
@Test
public void test1(){ 
Class1 class1=new Class1();
class1.method1();
}
```

I want to get the coverage report like this:

```
<package=pac1>
<class=class1>
<method=mehtod1>
</package>
```

Please let me know if there is a way of getting this.

My setup:
The app code is deployed on one box and it is instrumented. The test suite runs on a CI job.

Thanks
Kiran

Comment: Usually one would use Ant, Maven or Sonar to run JaCoCo...  You won't need to pre-instrument your code.

Comment: or by 'CI job', do you mean you are using Jenkins or similar?